# Using AppleScript to set a mail message to Plain Text

Tags: applescript, plaintext, apple-mail

I have an AppleScript that nicely collates information and creates an email message with attachments.

I cannot find a way for the script to set the message format to "Plain Text" which is required by the receiving inbox (rather than the default "Rich Text").

Is there an AppleScript way (or trick) to setting the message format to "Plain Text"?

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while trying to solve exactly this problem. Eventually I came up with the following solution:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message 
        with properties {visible:true,
                         subject:"message title",
                         sender:"sender@from.address",
                         content:mailBody}
    tell newMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {address:"mail@recipient.com"}
    end tell
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Make Plain Text" of ((process "Mail")'s (menu bar 1)'s (menu bar item "Format")'s (menu 1))
end tell
```

Hopefully someone will find this useful, I know I would have several hours ago!

This is tested on Mail versions 7.3 and 12.4. Newer, or older, versions might need different menu titles.

Answer (score 1):

Before the section in your script that creates a message, add this line.

```
 tell application "Mail" to set default message format to plain text
```

At the very end of the script add this to reset the value

```
 tell application "Mail" to set default message format to rich text
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an AppleScript error `Mail got an error: Can’t make string into type constant.`

Comment: Have you tried running the command by itself? It works for me on 10.6.8 with Mail 4.5.

Comment: I'm running Mail Version 6.0 on 10.8.1.  After looking through the AppleScript dictionary after your clue, I discovered that the format appears to have changes from `set default message format to plain text` to `set default message format to plain format`  This will then compile and run - but unfortunately the message is still in Rich Text.

Comment: So you can run the plain text script, THEN create a new message, type a few words into the body, highlight them and hit command B to make them bold?

Comment: Yep, even if I set as plain text and THEN create the message it still sends in Rich Text.  This is without any 'editing' of the mail message on my part.  If I check the mail headers of the message sent by AppleScript they will contain `Content-Type: TEXT/HTML;`.  Headers will only contain `Content-Type: text/plain;` if I manually send a message with Plain Text selected from within Mail.app.

Comment: @SoOverIt I can compile and run the new format (`set default message format to plain format`), but get an error message saying "Mail got an error: Can’t set default message format of outgoing message id 66 to plain format."  The suggestion from Paul Wagland above works, but seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: This worked for me in Ventura 13.5.2, but using the term `plain format` instead of `plain text`, eg: `set default message format to plain format` -- this is shown in the Script Library under Mail->Application->default message format (plain format/‌rich format) - where `plain format` and `rich format` are the two options to choose from. Note, though: the message was still sent with mime type "multipart/alternative", which put both the plain and the HTML versions in the message raw source.

Comment: And yet the text in the Plain Text section is prepended with '> '. Bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>**<kbd>t</kbd>** also to change the message format to `plain text`:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down, shift down}
```

Tested in Mail version 12.4

Answer (score 0):

Sad to say that Apple’s implementation is so broken that there is currently no way around it. You will have to suffer through it or find a way to send your mails through a commandline.

It got worse in macOS 13. Trying to have System Events send a keyboard shortcut will result in a permission error, even though all permissions are granted in System Settings.

Comment: Add the program into System Settings > Privacy & Security

Answer (score 0):

I have been using AppleScript to send email messages from within an application since 2013. As of MacOS 13 the text turned from Plain Text into Rich Text (I still have original sent messages from 2013 and even 2018 showing the text was Plain). However, a serious problem since MacOS 13 is that in this situation the characters '> ' (greater than and space) are prepended to the content of the message which causes some down-stream servers not to find any text at all. This is a bug.

Setting the format of the message to Plain Text does not remove those two new characters.

Trying to set the default to Plain Format did not have any effect (Rich and Plain are both included in the Rich Text email).

Using @Jonathan Cross's solution 
`tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down, shift down}`
 in MacOS 13.5.2 Mail 16.0 seems to require the removal of the application's assistive/accessibility entry in System Settings > Privacy & Security and adding it back in each time a new version of the program is created. (Sometimes this is not necessary when running in Xcode if the binary has not changed (in the Debug folder)). In terminal use 
`tccutil reset AppleEvents <your brilliant app's bundle id>`
 to reset the request alerts for permission to use System Events and control Mail.